# My PHP sites do not work with mysql router

Tags: mysql, php

I recently set up a mysql innodb cluster, and have configured mysqlrouter to sit in front of it.

On my PHP applications, if I change the port from 3306 to 6446, the application hangs when it tries to connect to the DB.  I never see any error messages.  I do have one PHP application that is working on port 6446: phpmyadmin.

The `mysql` commandline client works connecting to 6446.

I did find a bug that somebody filed on mysql saying that mysqlrouter doesn't support compression.  If I try a connection with compression, it fails.

```
elyograg@gandalf:~$ mysql -h db -P 6446 --ssl-mode=required --compression-algorithms=zlib,zstd
ERROR 2066 (HY000): Connection failed due to wrongly configured compression algorithm
```

Because the mysql client immediately errors when trying compression, seems like if compression were the problem, web pages would immediately abort with an error, not hang.

If I try a short PHP code snippet to connect using either PDO or mysqli, it hangs indefinitely connecting to 6446 and works connecting to 3306.

Because phpmyadmin (which uses mysqli) works, I think phpmyadmin must be setting some non-default mysqli option that allows it to work connecting to 6446.  I have tried finding the place in phpmyadmin where it creates the connection, but I am not very familiar with PHP code, so I haven't been able to find it.

What else can I do to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Now even phpmyadmin isn't working.  Best guess, there was some caching where a connection to 3306 was still active and usable.  I am restarting phpmyadmin, apache2, and haproxy after each change.